# Getting first part from the Postcode?

Tags: mysql

Using MySQL how to grab first part of the `data.postcode` field?

For example:

```
M40 1JY
M8 8NW
```

I want to display like this:

```
M40
M8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select substring(postcode, 1, locate (' ', postcode) - 1) from data;
```

`locate (' ', postcode)` returns the position of the space (), the first input, out of the second input (your column), you don't want to display the space so subtract 1 from this number.

`substring(data, start, length)` takes the substring of the data (your column) from the number of start, you want to start at the beginning, so this is 1, and displays the number of letters you enter in length, this is the result of `locate`.

Answer (score 3):

Use substring and locate:

```
select substring(postalcode,1,LOCATE(" ",postalcode)) from `data`
```

locate will find the index of blank and substring gives you the substrung until this Position.

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back sorry. Mysql has a 1 based string other as in programming language. Have changed my answer.

Answer (score 3):

The SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count) function is what you need. This function return the substring from string *str* before *count* occurrences of the delimiter *delim*. You can go the this link for more details. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index

For your problem,

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(postcode, ' ', 1) from YourTable;
```

will return

```
M40
M8
```